# how to code python to get a print if the array len count equal to text file lines count

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, notepad

I have 10 arrays on my array and I have 10 lines of numbers are in numbers.txt file.

How to code in python that I need to get a `print("The process completed")` if my Array len counts and text file line counts are equal then I need to print a message.

Array:

```
number = [124,589,478,547,745,256,321,654,665,888]
```

Text File: numbers.txt

```
124
589
478
547
745
256
321
654
665
888
```

Comment: Can you please show what you've tried before and indicate specifically where you are stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the ways to obtain what you want:

```
number = [124,589,478,547,745,256,321,654,665,888]
with open('numbers.txt','r') as f:
    if len(number) == len(f.readlines()):
        print("The process completed")
    else:
        print("The process is not yet completed")
```

Comment: Thank you for your support and it works

Answer (score 0):

Here if you just want to check the length you can do it like below.

```
number = [124,589,478,547,745,256,321,654,665,888]
f = open('numbers.txt','r')
if len(number) == len(f.readlines()):
    print("The process completed")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, its works well

Comment: Glad it helped you